# Angular cant find component on zero path

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

When im visiting my page without any sub-urls ( aka path: '') i get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
```

But if i click on a link, it would redirect me to `/(outside:login)`and it would work as supposed.
How can i make this apply when on path `''`?

Link i click to make it work when im on no url segment:

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {'outside': 'login'}}]" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
```

router:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
            path : 'bank',
            component: BankComponent,
            outlet: 'regular'
        },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo : 'login' ,
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
          {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginhandlerComponent,
            outlet: 'outside'
          },
])
```

display:

```
<div *ngIf="user.username">
                  <a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {'regular': 'druglab'}}]" routerLinkActive="active">Druglab</a>


    <div>
    <router-outlet name="regular"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="loggedin == false">
                  <a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {'outside': 'login'}}]" routerLinkActive="active">login</a>


// other things
    <div>
    <router-outlet name="outside"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts for /

```
loggedin = false;
user = {};
    this.CoreService.reloadUserData().subscribe((value) => {
      if (value.user) {
        this.user = value.user;
        this.loggedin = true;

      }
    });
```

How can i make it automatically go to the login module when not using a url segment / path?

Comment: I think you need the a starting **/** for the **redirectTo** path `redirectTo : '/login'`

Comment: @JayChase made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax has changed a bit. I got a redirect to work to a named outlet like this:

```
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/(outside:login)',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginhandlerComponent,
        outlet: 'outside'
      },
```

Comment: Then i get : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find the outlet outside to load 'LoginhandlerComponent'
Error: Cannot find the outlet outside to load 'LoginhandlerComponent'

Comment: @maria do you have two outlets in you code do you have corresponding router outlets in the view `<router-outlet name="outside"></router-outlet>`?

Comment: Yes. Both is there.